# How to approach this authentication mechanism in Jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am new to Jersey REST Framework , so please excuse if this is a dumb question .

I am using Tomcat with Hibernate and Jersey REST Webservices.

I have got set of HTML pages in my Web APP

```
login.html
dealer.html
sales.html
```

I dont want the User to access the HTML pages directly other than login.html

So  to resolve this issue ,  when submit is pressed , under login.html call

following call is made to the backend

```
@Path("/webchecklogin")
public class WebLoginCheck {
    @Context
    private HttpServletResponse response;
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getData(LoginInfo loginInfo ) throws JSONException,ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
     String ID = loginInfo.getID();
     String email = loginInfo.getEmail();
    //  validate this values with Database and if successfully logged in , stored them in session AND cookies also 
    }
}
```

And inside dealer.html and sales.html , on page ready i am calling a service as shown below

```
var checkcallajax = $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
      url: url + '/ORIENT/orn/checkifuserloggedin',
      jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
    success: function(response) {

    }
  })

@Path("/checkifuserloggedin")
public class CheckIfUserLoggedIn {
  @Context
    private HttpServletRequest request;
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String checkIfUserLoggedIn() throws JSONException,ClassNotFoundException, SQLException
    {
        // On what basis , should i check wheher the USER is logged or NOT
        // I tried storing data with Session and cookies , but i am unable to retrive them here     
        //return true or false 
        // based on true or false , i am redireting user to appropiate page
    }
    }
```

Could anybody please let me know how to approach this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestFUL web services are supposed to be stateless, so in theory, you could send the credential with every request, and that would be totally stateless from the "server point of view"

Most will find this cumbersome, resource intensive, and storing credentials on the client is somewhat bad from a security point.

The alternative approach could be that your login method returns a token, that needs to be re-sent (in a header maybe) to the server with every request.

- The client must know how to store it (session cookie? on the domain
  serving html, if you are in a CORS scenario)
- The server must know how to validate the token.

On top of it, the validation of the Token can be done in a JaxRS Filter... before reaching your service entry point. And even better, this filter could add roles to the request context, so you can the use the @RolesAllowed annotation with your services.

I "very personnally" avoid relying on the javax.servlet.Session, as this is fundamentally stateful. But, you should be able to do it, given that the clients stores the jSessionId (other other cookie name) in a session cookie. If it does not work, you might have CORS or other domain specific problem, preventing the client from storing and returning this cookie automatically.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You can access the header using the `@HeaderParam` annotation.